# React native IOS mail callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, native, react-native

Looking for a way in react native to implement the action of "Open in" if a .pdf is attached to a email or any other extension I may wan?. I know it can be done the following way http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

But how would react native handle it, how would the app data be passed back forth, and how can I get it to open a certain parts of the application such as a certain component?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail supplies an API to show the MFMailComposeViewController of iOS.